# Como optimizar consulta sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

sucede que tengo una tabla con n registros... 20 por ejemplo... De esos 20, 5 registros pertenecen a 4 personas, es decir que hay 4 personas a las que se les registro 5 veces en esa tabla, para un total de 20(a modo de ejemplo)... La consulta que debo obtener es de solo 4 registros, y corresponden al ultimo reigstro de cada persona, teniendo en cuenta que esa tabla tiene una columna **fechainicio** en donde el valor de la fecha de varia de manera ascendente. Tengo el siguiente codigo sql:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLA T1 WHERE T1.fechainicio=(SELECT MAX(fechainicio) FROM MYTABLA WHERE idpersona=T1.idpersona)
```

Como se puede ver, hago 2 cosultas(select's) a la misma tabla..
Existe alguna forma de mejorar esa consulta?? Pues habran miles de registros... Ademas de que tambien hago JOINS a otras 3 tablas..

Editando mi pregunta para una mejor explicacion....

[image: AQUI MUESTRO LAS CONSULTAS SQL QUE TENGO O ESTOY PROBANDO]

El primer SELECT con los JOINs hace todo perfecto, obteniendo un resultado asi:
[image: Un total de 9 registros]
Genera un resultado de 9 registros, la tabla tiene 10 pero hay un usuario que esta 2 veces y solo traera el ultimo de ese usuario...

En cambio el query que me da @LCC me genera todos los 10 registros asi:
[image: 10 registros]

Tengo entendido que usar subconsultas dentro del where hace mas lenta la consulta, pero nose como hacer para quitar esa subconsulta del where de tal manera que me siga trayendo los mismos resultados que necesito(el ultimo de cada usuario), y asi optimizar la consulta.

---

Comment: Una cosa es arreglar esta consulta, pero eso no quiere decir que vamos a poder arreglar tu consulta final. Teniendo en cuenta eso, si queres que traiga todos los registros, y podes asegurar que todos (pero todos) los otros campos son iguales, se puede hacer con un group by sin problemas.

Comment: También es importante mencionar que identifiques si las tablas que estas utilizando tienen indices para poder aprovecharlos.

Comment: @Eduardo Castro, gracias por responder... Estuve leyendo sobre los indices en postgresql... Incluso, creé un indice para la tabla en el campo "fechainicio" pero nose si debo colocar alguna sintaxis en el sql para usar el indice, o el mismo motor de postgres sabrá que ya hay un indice y lo usara.. Como es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta que estaba elaborando es exactamente igual a lo que has llegado, simplemente te respondo por que agrego algo más de información que eventualmente puede ser útil. Lo que buscas puedes resolverlo así:

```
SELECT  pg.* 
    FROM pagoperiodicos pg 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  idusuario, 
                        MAX(fechainicio) as fechainicio
                        FROM pagoperiodicos 
                        GROUP BY idusuario
        ) pg2 
        ON pg.idusuario = pg2.idusuario
        AND pg.fechainicio = Pg2.fechainicio
```

En castellano: Recuperamos la fecha máxima de `pagoperiodicos` por `idusuario` y simplemente un `JOIN` entre tabla y subconsulta. No logramos quitarnos la subconsulta de encima, pero la empleamos de una manera que suele ser más óptima, digo suele, por que los "caminos del motor son inescrutables". Seguramente esta consulta agradecería mucho que `fechainicio` tenga un índice.

Ahora bien, ¿es necesario hacerlo de esta forma? y tal vez no, pero depende de las columnas que finalmente vayas a mostrar. Si se repiten filas pero las columnas que vayas a mostrar siempre tienen los mismos valores, puedes hacer directamente un `GROUP BY` de todas las columnas y resuelves el tema, creo que a eso apunta @gbianchi en sus comentarios.

Otra aclaración importante es, que esta forma solo funcionará si efectivamente  `fechainicio` es un dato único, en la práctica solo los autonuméricos lo son, por lo que si eventualmente pudiéramos decir que `idpago` guarda relación con la antigüedad de los registros, podríamos reemplazar `MAX(fechainicio)` por `MAX(idpago)`.

Comment: Estas totalmente en lo cierto!! idpago guarda relacion con la antiguedad de los registros, pero se me presentaron casos en donde mi cliente habia registrado el pago actual de la persona, y despues cuando tuviera tiempo, regiistraria los pagos anteriores, de tal manera que el pago reciente que tenia la fecha maxima quedaba de ultimo...
Gracias por responder!

Answer (score 1):

Si las filas que corresponden a una sola persona solamente se diferencian por el campo de fechainicio la siguiente query te sirve.

Si necesitas mas campos, con informar en la SELECT y en el GROUP BY los campos que son iguales para una misma persona deberías poder sacar la información que necesitas, y para los campos que son diferentes puedes utilizar las formulas (MAX,MIN,COUNT,etc).

```
 SELECT idpersona, MAX(fechainicio)
    FROM MYTABLA T1
    GROUP BY idpersona
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta. Mira el comentario que le deje. Dice que la consulta forma parte de una consulta mas grande, y si necesita todos los campos es en ese caso no le sirve. Ten en cuenta siempre que si se comentan cosas en la pregunta, siempre es mejor esperar a que quien pregunto aclare esas cosas.

Comment: Muy bien, perdona por la intromisión. Lo tendré en cuenta para futuros casos.

Comment: gbianchi, no entiendo a que quieres llegar? Mi inquietud es saber si la consulta que estoy mostrando se puede optimizar, de tal manera que la subconsulta que se encuentra dentro del WHERE sea eliminada.. Nosé si sea posible, pues como comento en la descripcion, necesito traer el ultimo INSERT que se le hizo a la persona... La tabla contiene los pagos MES A MES que la persona hizo...

Comment: No hay problema!! no es ninguna intromision!! solo tenlo en cuenta para que tus respuestas no sean votadas negativamente. Tambien mira [answer]. en toda respuesta se pide que haya una explicación del codigo. Sigue asi! ;)

Comment: Estamos hablando de muchas personas, entonces una persona puede haber pagado 1 año, de mes a mes... Deben haber 12 registros de una sola persona, pero solo necesito traer el ultimo registro de esa persona, teniendo en cuenta que son muchas personas...

Comment: @NelsonSepulveda en ese caso, este query te trae el id de la persona y es totalmente correcto.

Comment: @gbianchi, Edite la pregunta para que fuese mas clara, y la respueta que da el no retorna los datos que necesito.

Comment: No te ddvuelve lo que vos queres, porque como te pregunte en el comentario en la pregunta (no en esta respuesta) necesitamos saber si efectivamente necesitamos todos los acmpos o solo algunos. Este query si anda, pero vos no lo escribiste asi. De ahi el problema que estas teniendo. Por favor los comentarios y observaciones a la prefunta hacelos en la pregunta

Comment: @gbianchi el query si anda, pero habia que saberlo poner, es decir en el from como un join, y eso era lo que no encontraba, donde y como ponerlo.

Answer (score -2):

```html
SELECT pg.*, pg.valorplan-sum(p.valorabonado) as debe, sum(p.valorabonado) as totalpagado, count(*) as pagosrealizados, 
       (u.nombre || ' ' || u.apellido) as nombres, u.cedula, u.telefono, pl.nombreplan, e.nombreempleado, em.nombreempleado as empleado_actualizado
 FROM pagoperiodicos pg
 LEFT JOIN pagos p ON p.idpago=pg.idpago 
 LEFT JOIN planes pl ON pg.idplan=pl.idplan
 INNER JOIN empleado e ON e.idempleado=pg.idempleado 
 LEFT JOIN empleado em ON em.idempleado=pg.idempleadoactualizado 
 INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.idusuario=pg.idusuario 
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT idusuario, max(fechainicio) as maxima FROM pagoperiodicos GROUP BY idusuario
 ) as R
 ON pg.idusuario=R.idusuario AND pg.fechainicio=R.maxima
 GROUP BY pg.idpago, pl.idplan, u.idusuario, e.idempleado, em.idempleado
 ORDER BY fechaderegistro DESC
```

Comment: La verdad que despues de ver esta solucion, no entiendo como le pueda servir a alguien mas. No tiene nada que ver con el query que estabas planteando, y una de las soluciones que te dieron es parte de lo que pusiste aca. Te pediria que la proxima vez seas mucho mas claro con la pregunta (y no me refiero a extension, si no a claridad de lo que tenes y queres hacer)

Comment: Si tiene que ver con el query que estaba planeando, solo que no lo coloque completo para no enrredar tanto al lector, de igual forma como @Patricio Moracho dio respuesta es lo mejor forma de optimizar la consulta. Los select dentro del where son mas lentos que colocandolos en el FROM, de 800 milisegundos que duraba, ahora solo me demora 250 ~ 300 ms.